# buscar resultados de una tabla con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero buscar resultados de una tabla con PHP y MySQL a partir de un inputy clasico boton buscar.

Hasta ahora he podido realizar esto, les dejo el extracto:

```
<h3 class="box-title">Reporte de su pedido</h3>
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>                                            
                                        <tr>                                                
                                            <th>CÉDULA</th>
                                            <th>NRO PEDIDO</th>                                                                                   
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php
                                        

                                                                                  
                                        if(!isset($_POST['buscar_pedido'])){

                                        $_POST['buscar_pedido'] = "";

                                        $buscar_pedido = $_POST['buscar_pedido'];

                                        }                                          
                                        
                                        $sql= "SELECT * FROM creadas WHERE cedula LIKE '%".$buscar_pedido."%' OR npedido LIKE '%".$buscar_pedido."%'";
                                        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                                        
                                        while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                            

                                        
                                        ?>                                    
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['cedula'] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['npedido'] ?></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        
                                        <?php 
                                        }                                            
                                        ?>                                                
                                    </tbody>                                   
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>               
                    </div>                       
                </div>
            </div>
```

con esto he logrado que se muestre esos resultados en esa tabla. Ahora bien, en realidad no quieren que se muestren los resultados a menos que yo coloque la cedula y oprima el boton BUSCAR.

```
<form class="form-inline" action="" method="POST">                                                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Instroduzca cédula del comprador </label>
                                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="buscar_pedido" id="buscar_pedido"  placeholder="Ejemplo: 19226521">
                                </div>                                    
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Buscar pedido</button>
                            </form>
```

de verdad he intentado y visto muchos videos pero no logro hacerlo, muchas gracias a quienes puedan aportarme su grano de arena para lograrlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado

Una solución sin recurrir a javascript podría ser la siguiente:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            
            <!---- Esto es solo importación del bootstrap --->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <!---- Zona del formulario de busqueda --->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <form class="form-inline" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; //hace referncia al mismo archivo?>" method="POST">                                                                
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Introduzca cédula del comprador </label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="buscar_pedido" placeholder="Ejemplo: 19226521">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" type="submit">Buscar pedido</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                            
                            </div>                                    
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!---- Fin zona formualrio de busqueda -->
                
                <!---- Zona Tabla resultados ---->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Reporte de su pedido</h3>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>                                            
                                    <tr>                                                
                                        <th>CÉDULA</th>
                                        <th>NRO PEDIDO</th>                                                                                   
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
                                    //configuracion base de datos
                                    $conexion = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");
                                
                                    //Comprobamos si las variables fueron enviadas
                                    if($_POST){
                                        //Comprobar si la variable de busqueda exista y no este vacia
                                        if(isset($_POST['buscar_pedido']) && !empty($_POST['buscar_pedido'])){
                                            
                                            $buscar_pedido = $_POST['buscar_pedido'] ?: NULL; //Esta comprobacion puede estar de mas, pero aplico elvis
                                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM creadas WHERE cedula LIKE '%".$buscar_pedido."%' OR npedido LIKE '%".$buscar_pedido."%'"; //Query
                                            $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); //ejecutar query
                                            
                                            while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['cedula'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['npedido'] ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php
                                            }
                                            
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            //En el caso que la variable de busqueda este vacia
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"> Sin resultados </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php
                                        } //Cierra if de validacion de variable busqueda
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        //En el caso que no hayan variable se devuelve una fila vacia
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"> Sin resultados </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php      
                                    } //Cierra el if de validacion $_POST
                                ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>                
                </div>
                <!--- Fon zona tabla de resultados --->
                
            </div>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

La base de tu propuesta de código esta bien, solo bastaba ordenar algunos criterios. Por ejemplo para no recurrir a otro archivo donde hacer la validación de los datos enviados en el formulario, solo basta con referirse al mismo archivo en el `action` del `form`. De esta manera obtenemos la información a consultar en el query, y la imprimimos en la tabla. Si no se cumplen ciertas condiciones señalamos que no hay resultados.

Aqui puedes ver una prueba de como funciona el codigo
http://test.ingenierialabs.com/CristianB/1/index.php

Comment: Ricardo, excelente, gracias por ayudarme a reorganizar mis ideas. Saludos y valoro tu esfuerzo.